# Issue with list printing

Tags: python

ok I'm trying to make a code to display a list of admin privileges. I made the code and things work but it gives me a weird display before any of the list items:

input code:

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(*privileges):
        privileges
        
    def show_privileges(*privileges):
        print("these are your privileges:")
        for privilege in privileges:
            print(f"\t{privilege}")


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, username):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, username)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


Admin = Admin('Admin', '', '' ,'')
Admin.privileges.show_privileges('can add post', 'can delete post', 
    'can ban user')
```

output:

```
 these are your privileges:
        <__main__.Privileges object at 0x7facd3c5f4f0>
        can add post
        can delete post
        can ban user
```

Comment: `self` is the first argument when you invoke it as a method. Type the function as `def show_privileges(self, *privileges)`.

Comment: better don't use the same name for class and variable `Admin = Admin(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `show_privileges(*privileges)` is being given `self` as the first argument. That is the weird output that you are seeing, self is being printed. You need to either include self in the definition as:

```
def show_privileges(self, *privileges):
    print("these are your privileges:")
    for privilege in privileges:
        print(f"\t{privilege}")
```

Or you can slice the list to avoid the first element:

```
def show_privileges(*privileges):
    print("these are your privileges:")
    for privilege in privileges[1:]:
        print(f"\t{privilege}")
```

The first option would be more typical i think.
To read more about `self` and how it works in python you can read the [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp) mentioned by [codewelldev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13911868/codewelldev).

Comment: You could include this tutorial link about the `self` argument: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp